# Display row numbers in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

How to display result row number in SQLite?

I have my select statement returning requested values, but how can I add a column displaying row numbers. for example 1,2,3... etc.

Comment: Probably best done in code when fetching the results. It can be done, but not without (un-necessarily?) complicating your SQL.

Comment: Why can't you just count the number of records returned so far?